# Share Target and JumpListItemBackgroundConverter

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I've added the Share Target declaration to my app for the data format WebLink and everything works as expected. However, when I add a JumpListItemBackgroundConverter or JumpListItemForegroundConverter anywhere in the app, the app hangs on the splash screen when you enter the app using the Share from IE. No exception, no crash, the debugger doesn't even stop. All I get is a cryptic error in the output window, "The program '...' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'." The documentation for those converters say they're fine with universal apps, just that they've been moved to a different namespace. Has anyone been able to get these two things to work in the same app? If so, where did I go wrong? Or is there something better than those two converters to get the LongListSelector look and feel?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new universal app. I chose hub.
2. Add a share target of format WebLink to the appxmanifest declarations.
3. Add a new page to point the share contract to.
4. Add the OnShareTargetActivated code to app.xaml.cs to open the new page. See code below
5. Add a JumpListItemBackgroundConverter to the resources of the main page of the app. You don't need to apply it to anything, just declaring it is enough to break the sharing.
6. Go to IE and share a link. It should hang on the splash screen.

Code for app.xaml.cs:

```
    protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
    {    
         // Replace SharePage with the name of the share target page
         var rootFrame = new Frame();
         rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SharePage), args.ShareOperation);
         Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
         Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in the emulator. It works if you test on a physical device.

[MSDN Forum - JumpListItemBackgroundConverter and Share Target in Windows Phone 8.1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/0d70e13e-adb7-4050-b17b-fa21d18d45ce/jumplistitembackgroundconverter-and-share-target-in-windows-phone-81?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK)